# How to edit a "$" inside css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have bought this wordpress theme: https://preview.themeforest.net/item/front-multipurpose-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/25428980?_ga=2.153784312.1521787254.1606987660-2047182645.1600211466

I'm trying to change the logo width, when I'm clicking on inspect, I get this code which I can edit:

```
.u-header__navbar-brand > img {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width: 9.375rem;   ----> This I want to be 13.3rem
}
```

But when I go inside the wordpress css file, I get this code:

```
.u-header__navbar-brand {
  &,
  & > img {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width: $header-navbar-brand-width;
  }
```

I have tried to replace the $header-navbar-brand-width; with "width: 13.3rem;" but nothing happens.
Does any one how I can edit the logo width on this wordpress website?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The theme might be loading `min` file of the stylesheet. Have you checked that ? Also the variable `$header-navbar-brand-width` probably would be defined in the same file

Comment: It looks more like a scss than a clear css. You should look for something like min css file or anything that could be compile from this scss.

Comment: Rather than editing the css file, try adding the style to overwrite this style via the additional css section in WordPress theme customizer.

Answer (score 0):

The overall problem which I can see here is that it looks more like a scss for me than css.

If you're not familiar with compiling it and etc. the best solution in my opinion for you would be to install some wordpress plugin that can inject new stylesheets to overwrite the default ones from the theme.

Here is option that I would go with:

1. Install this plugin:
   For example
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/
   There are lots of plugins with that kind of functionality so you can go with with anything else here. All of them work similarly.

with that you can just write simple css files that will for sure overwrite the default stylesheet

2. After doing that you could simply inject new css rule that makes logo bigger. For example something like this:

```css
.u-header__navbar-brand > img {
    width: 50px;
  }
```

3. Save it and it should work fine with any kind of theme that is applied

Comment: I have another questions if you mind, I'm trying to make the menu items so that when I click on them, the web scrolls down to that specific section? Is there anyway to do that without any real coding experience? I have tried read about #id , but I dont get it.

Comment: #id way is the easiest one but with that you have to be sure that element you want to scroll to have to "contain" the same id

Comment: It would be really nice of you If you could accept my answer as solution @rekkz